# CakePhp v2 can not connect to Firebase with a domain with ssl certificate

Tags: php, ssl, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have problems when inserting data to firebase from a domain with certificate (ssl), from LOCALHOST and a Domain `http://` works corractamete, but from one `https://` does not work.

This comes out in the debug (I'm using **CakePhpv2**)

> Error: [SocketException] stream_socket_client(): Peer certificate
>   CN=`firebaseio.com' did not match expected CN=`xxxxxx.firebaseio.com'
>   stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto
>   stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://uxxxxxxxx.com:443
>   (Unknown error)

Answer (score 1):

When making requests to SSL services HttpSocket will attempt to validate the SSL certifcate using peer validation. If the certificate fails peer validation or does not match the hostname being accessed the connection will fail, and an exception will be thrown. By default HttpSocket will use the mozilla certificate authority file to verify SSL certificates. You can use the following options to configure how SSL certificates are handled:

- **ssl_verify_peer** Set to false to disable SSL verification. This is not
  recommended.
- **ssl_verify_host** Set to false if you wish to ignore
  hostname match errors when validating certificates.
- **ssl_allow_self_signed** Set to true to enable self-signed certificates
  to be accepted. This requires ssl_verify_peer to be enabled.
- **ssl_cafile** Set to the absolute path of the Certificate Authority file
  that you wish to use for verifying SSL certificates.

  $socket = new HttpSocket(array(
      'ssl_verify_host' => false
  ));

See [CakePHP HttpSocket Handling SSL certificates](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/httpsocket.html#handling-ssl-certificates)